# Looping data - loops twice only loads one data

Tags: php

I have a while loop that creates an array prior to json encoding the data but although i have tested it and i get 2 rows returned and it loops twice..my json encode only shows one of the rows of data =/

This is my php:

```
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
         player t1 INNER JOIN game t2
         ON t1.sid=t2.id
        WHERE uid='1'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){

    echo 'looped<br/>'; //testing row count

        $data[$row['x']] = Array();
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][0] = $row['bid'];
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][1] = $row['sid'];
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][2] = $row['width'];
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][3] = $row['height'];
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][4] = $row['offsetx'];
        $data[$row['x']][$row['y']][5] = $row['offsety'];

  }

 $data1 = json_encode($data);
```

I had 2 loops in total but only one data set for my json which is confusing me:

```
 {"10":{"11":["1","22","1","1","0","0"]}}
```

Its missing the first row of data which would of created this aswell as the one above:

```
{"10":{"10":["1","7","2","2","0","32"]}};
```

I'm wondering if im overwriting some how ? I thought it would not given im assign to arrays and their X:Y are different.

Comment: what is the possible values of $row['x']

Comment: @JohnnyCraig you can see them in the json's the first number is X second number is Y :)

Comment: It appears the values of `x` in the row that exists and the row that is missing are the same, so the second row destroys the first.

Comment: @DCoder this was my suspicion but I can't work out a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    $data[$row['x']] = Array();
}
```

You should only set it if it doesn't exist yet:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    if(!array_key_exists($row['x'], $data)) {
        $data[$row['x']] = Array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate and assign your $data array outside of the loop.

Comment: But $row['x'] is not set until in the loop.